# GPUImage: Efficient way to reflect GPUImageView?

Tags: ios, reflection, calayer, gpuimage

I want to reflect a GPUImageView where a GPUImageVideoCamera targets the GPUImageView.

Possible idea: Subclass GPUImageView and use CAReplicatorLayer.

```
 @interface MySubview : GPUImageView
 @end

 @implementation MySubview

 + (Class) layerClass {
    return [CAReplicatorLayer class];
 }

 @end
```

Then reflect using layoutSubviews. I'm stumped.

Example of the reflection I want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "reflect"?

Comment: I updated the question with an example image

Comment: For the best reflection of a video stream, I'd look at writing a custom fragment shader for a filter that you could use to process the video and generate the reflection within the filter stream. The result of the video + reflection could then be sent to a single GPUImageView.